# I want to solve this problem > The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, opencv

I tried this code. but error occured!

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

## import library

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pickle 
from cv2 import VideoCapture
from cv2 import waitKey
from keras.models import load_model
```

## make object

```
framewidth = 640
frameHeight = 480
brightness = 180
threshold = 0.90
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
```

## set up video camera and load model

my_model.h5 file is uploaded this link >>> https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/kimseungk/traffic-sign-classfication-modelcnn-h5-file

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, framewidth)
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
cap.set(10, brightness)
model = load_model("C:/Users/k2h2j3/traffic/Train/my_model.h5")
model.summary()
```

## traffic sign classfication

```
def grayscale(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return img

def equalize(img):
    img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
    return img

def preprocessing(img):
    img = grayscale(img)
    img = equalize(img)
    img = img/255
    return img

def getCalssName(classNo):
    if classNo == 0: 
        return 'speed Limit 20km/h'
    elif classNo == 1: 
        return 'speed Limit 40km/h'
    elif classNo == 2: 
        return 'speed Limit 50km/h'
    elif classNo == 3: 
        return 'speed Limit 60km/h'
    elif classNo == 4: 
        return 'speed Limit 70km/h'
    elif classNo == 5: 
        return 'speed Limit 80km/h'
    elif classNo == 6: 
        return 'end of speed Limit 80km/h'
    elif classNo == 7: 
        return 'speed Limit 100km/h'
    elif classNo == 8: 
        return 'speed Limit 120km/h'
    elif classNo == 9: 
        return 'No passing'
    elif classNo == 10:
        return 'No passing for vehicles over 3.5 metric tons'
    elif classNo == 11: 
        return 'Right-of-way at the next intersection'
    elif classNo == 12: 
        return 'prioirty road'
    elif classNo == 13: 
        return 'Yield'
    elif classNo == 14: 
        return 'Stop'
    elif classNo == 15: 
        return 'No vehicles'
    elif classNo == 16:
        return 'Veh > 3.5 tons prohibited'
    elif classNo == 17:
        return 'No entry'
    elif classNo == 18:
        return 'General caution'
    elif classNo == 19:
        return 'Dangerous curve left'
    elif classNo == 20: 
        return 'Dangerous curve right'
    elif classNo == 21:
        return 'Double curve'
    elif classNo == 22:
        return 'Bumpy road'
    elif classNo == 23:
        return 'Slippery road'
    elif classNo == 24:
        return 'Road narrows on the right'
    elif classNo == 25: 
        return 'Road work'
    elif classNo == 26:
        return 'Traffic signals'
    elif classNo == 27: 
        return 'Pedetrians'
    elif classNo == 28:
        return 'Children crossing'
    elif classNo == 29:
        return 'Bicycles crossing'
    elif classNo == 30:
        return 'Beware of ice/snow'
    elif classNo == 31:
        return 'Wild animals crossing'
    elif classNo == 32:
        return 'End speed + passing limits'
    elif classNo == 33:
        return 'Turn right ahead'
    elif classNo == 34:
        return 'Turn left ahead'
    elif classNo == 35:
        return 'Ahead only'
    elif classNo == 36:
        return 'Go straight or right'
    elif classNo == 37:
        return 'Go straight or left'
    elif classNo == 38:
        return 'keep right'
    elif classNo == 39:
        return 'keep left'
    elif classNo == 40:
        return 'Roundabout mandatory'
    elif classNo == 41:
        return 'End of no passing'
    elif : classNo == 42:
        return 'End no passing veh > 3.5 tons'
```

## problem occured

```
while True:

success, imgOrignal = cap.read()

img = np.asarray(imgOrignal)
img = cv2.resize(img, (32, 32))
img = preprocessing(img)
cv2.imshow("Processed Image", img)
img = img.reshape(1, 32, 32, 1)
cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "CLASS: " , (20, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.putText(imgOrignal, "PROBABILITY: ", (20, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
predictions = model.predict(img)
classIndex = model.predict(img)
probabilityValue =np.amax(predictions)

if probabilityValue > threshold:
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal,str(classIndex)+" "+str(getCalssName(classIndex)), (120, 35), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA) 
    cv2.putText(imgOrignal, str(round(probabilityValue*100,2) )+"%", (180, 75), font, 0.75, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)        
cv2.imshow("Result", imgOrignal)


if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
```

occured error message image> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htNN5.jpg)

Comment: This elif chain makes my eyes hurt. It would also help if you provided exact error traceback, especially where exactly it occurs in the code.

Comment: The `elif` chain is really bad practice. Use a dictionary or even a list containing the strings instead.

Comment: I think it's because you compare classIndex to a int, which can work if it's an array with 1 element but not when there is many.

Comment: Does this help if classNo == '0' or if '0' in classNo:?